# Google Maps Chart Cities in region

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization

Is it possible show cities just in exact region? 
For example I have this map and some cities with *region* 'UA'.
Example map:

> http://jsfiddle.net/jQbpR/6/

```
 var options = {
            region: 'UA',
            displayMode: 'markers',
            resolution: 'provinces',
            colorAxis: { colors: ['yellow', 'green'] }
        };
```

At this map I have city with name 'Novaya', in this country we are have few cities with this same name. How to show this city exactly in region 'UA-14' near other cities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the region-code to the data, e.g. `Novaya,UA-14`

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/ZVGHG/

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome trick. I would have recommended looking up lat/longitude for each city (which is faster to render anyway), but this is a tremendous trick for a few points!